# Laminate flooring direction in large room

Tags: flooring, laminate

My room is 24x42
Estetically I'd like the planks to run long
It's a good quality laminate that is floating

I'm told that if I go long, it's too long and will require a seam. (Ugly!)

So I'm advised to lay planks the short way

Ideas? Suggestions? Feedback?

Comment: The more specific info you give the better the answers will be for example: 24x42 inches?meters?hectares? what make/model is your flooring? which way do your floor joists run? How are you planning to transition out of the...closet? pantry?  This probably seems anal but these are (some of) the considerations a professional flooring installer would consider before setting a floor.

Comment: Have you read the installation instructions? They might require this or that, which might make the decision for you.

Comment: Also.  Won't you have lots of seams? The planks are usually only 2-4 ft. by a few inches, so you'll have lots of seams.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a different laminate or switch to engineered wood.  Found this [install instruction](http://www.builddirect.com/pdf/laminate/eurafloor/installation/eurafloors-installation.pdf) for laminate and it does mention adding an expansion joint for larger rooms.  Max room size before expansion is 33' for the panel length and 26' for the panel width.  Switching the panels to run on the short side of the room is not going to help since it will still require an expansion gap in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I've run ikea laminate flooring longways in a 20 x 40 foot office. This worked fine and I'm really pleased with the result. One advantage I had was that the ends are not visible at the top or the bottom so I was able to leave a decent amount of expansion space. I'd only risk it if you could leave a good amount of expansion / contraction space too. Obviously your laminate may expand more or less than ikea laminate though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering easthetically, if you run the planks the long way along the length of the room, it might enhance the long and narrow feel of the room.  Whereas, if you run the planks the other way, it may give the room the appearance of balance between width and length.  I personally would not run them along the long length but the other way.